# Data not inserting into realtime database, but the user is created in Firebase authentication

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have an app which worked well some days back. I'm trying to insert data into the realtime database, but the data is not not inserting, and I don't get any error. My rule is set to true

```
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  DatabaseReference usersRef =
      FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("users");
  registerUser(BuildContext context) async {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return ProgressDialog(msg: 'Authenticating');
        });
    final User firebaseUser = (await _firebaseAuth
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                email: emailController.text.trim(),
                password: passwordController.text.trim())
            .catchError((errorMsg) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      displayToastMsg("Error: " + errorMsg.toString(), context);
    }))
        .user;

    if (firebaseUser != null) {
      Map userDataMap = {
        "name": nameController.text.trim(),
        "phone": phoneController.text.trim(),
        "email": emailController.text.trim(),
      };
      usersRef.child(firebaseUser.uid).set(userDataMap);
      displayToastMsg('Account created successfully', context);
      // Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
      //     context, MainScreen.routeScreen, (route) => false);
    } else {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      displayToastMsg('User was not created', context);
    }
  }
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Are any messages showing in the log output? Especially on the `usersRef.child(firebaseUser.uid).set(userDataMap)` line?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running FirebaseApp.configure in the main file? Assuming the database url is correct in the configure method you should be able to create a reference by => `usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('users/${firebaseUser.uid}');` and then
upload the userMap by `usersRef.set(userDataMap)`.